# regarding understanding a python function using logical operators

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I once read the following python function,

```
def f1(i, num_digits):
    return np.array([i >> d & 1 for d in range(num_digits)])
```

I am not very clear on how does the part of `i >> d & 1` work. Running `f1(2,5)` will return `[0,1,0,0,0]`

Comment: These are [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function creates a list containing the last bit of `i` after it got shifted `index` times to the right.

Sounds cryptic? It is.

Here is what happens:

The list comprehension creates a list of size `num_digits-1`, using the values of the range expression (which are 0 to `num_digits-1`) to calculate the value of the item that is supposed to be at that index of the list. To calculate the value of the list item, the integer `i` is taken and the bits of it are shifted to the right by `d` places, where `d` is the current value of the range we are iterating over to construct our list. The `>>` (bitshift-right) operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator, so this calculation is done first. The last step to calculating the list value is performing a logical `&` of the bitshifted value and the value `1`. This step requires some thinking, but what it does is it returns the last bit of our bitshifted value.

This is easier if you actually do the steps on a piece of paper. See, how the only time the last bit of our computation is 1 is if we shift the bit value of 2 to the right by one place (hence the list entry at index 1 is a 1 and the rest are 0's):

```
Index 0: 2 (dec) = 10 (bin) -> >> 0 -> 10 (bin) -> 10 & 01 = 00 (bin) = 0 (dec)
Index 1: 2 (dec) = 10 (bin) -> >> 1 -> 01 (bin) -> 01 & 01 = 01 (bin) = 1 (dec)
Index 2: 2 (dec) = 10 (bin) -> >> 2 -> 00 (bin) -> 00 & 01 = 00 (bin) = 0 (dec)
# From here on it will be the same as index 2, because we are only shifting 0's
```

I hope this helps you understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` lets us demonstrate this action in a nice table:

```
In [1633]: np.arange(10)[:,None]>>np.arange(5)
Out[1633]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [5, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [6, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [7, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [8, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [9, 4, 2, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Looks like `& 1` turns this into a binary digit representation:

```
In [1634]: np.arange(10)[:,None]>>np.arange(5) & 1
Out[1634]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

The bit shift is effectively a divide by powers of 2

```
In [1641]: np.arange(10)[:,None]//(2**np.arange(5))
Out[1641]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [5, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [6, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [7, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [8, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [9, 4, 2, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

and a modulus 2 remainder:

```
In [1642]: np.arange(10)[:,None]//(2**np.arange(5)) % 2
Out[1642]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```